# How can I enumerate methods that have MethodAttributes.PrivateScope using Reflection?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

How can I enumerate methods that have MethodAttributes.PrivateScope using Reflection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
Type t = typeof(MyClass);
var Methods = t.GetMethods(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

foreach (MethodInfo mInfo in Methods)
{
    if (mInfo.Attributes == MethodAttributes.PrivateScope))
    {
        // Do what needs to be done.
    }
}
```